# How to open multiple chrome profiles with selenium at same time?

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to open multiple windows with different profiles, tried:

```
options.add_argument(f"--user-data-dir={expanduser}\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\")
options.add_argument(f"profile-directory={profile}")
```

but this just switched the profiles, so it is on the same path, and if I tried to run it multiple times, it gives me this error : `user data directory is already in use, please specify a unique value for --user-data-dir argument, or don't use --user-data-dir`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I found was to create a whole new `User Data` Directory:

```
options.add_argument(f"--user-data-dir={expanduser}\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\{random_name}\\")
```

this will create a full new chrome, not just a profile.

Comment: Can anyone make sure that this is the only way to achieve my result ?